# Hi , why my try block is skipping and control is going to finally block with out giving any exception?

Tags: java, rest, try-catch, finally

my code is like below

```
try{
    System.out.println("index"+index);
    System.out.println("Inside getPayloadFromKibana elsatic host" + elasticHost);
    RestHighLevelClient restClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient
                    .builder(new HttpHost(elasticHost, 7008, "http"))//here port number is differnt.
                    .setRequestConfigCallback(
                            requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(60000).setSocketTimeout(60000))
                    .setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(60000));
    System.out.println("restClient ::"+restClient);
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    -----
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    finally{}
```

when i execute my project in debug mode i see that my controll is going to finally block when ever it runs on RestHighLevelClient creating object , and it is not giving any exception or not coming into catch block , why it is behaving like this can any one please help here?

Comment: Could it be that somewhere in creating the RestHighLevel, a `Throwable` is being thrown?  Not all `Throwable` objects are `Exception` objects.

Comment: There is no statement in the catch block, so if an exception is thrown, there is no line the debugger could stop at.

Answer (score -1):

You may not be using debug mode correctly.
Try expanding the Catch block and test using .